# stripe_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: flutter, dart

i have recently facing a issue when i ran my flutter project in Android Studio like this, Execution failed for task ':stripe_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> error: invalid source release: 17

i tried several attempts to solve this error, but not yet found a solution, so if anyone has a solution to this then help me with that.fl

Comment: updating java version may resolve the issues .

Comment: well, i had already JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8, still can't fix the issue

Comment: may be another issues . The issues you have poseted here related to java version .Debug the code .

Answer (score 0):

Update your ***Java*** Version . And add this line in build.gradle file:-

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Comment: I have this set version of JAVA only associated with my project but still facing the same issue